# How to integrate SaaS subscription/contract product on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, saas

I'm trying to figure out how to write the first stage of integrating a Saas product into the AWS Marketplace. Please tell me who wrote such code, how to use [AWS SDK for Java V2] to perform at least the first stage of integration. I didn't find this among the AWS documentation [integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/saas-integrate-contract.html)

According to the documentation,after a customer subscribes to your product, they will be redirected to the fulfillment URL.
The redirect is a POST request & includes a temporary token.
Your app then needs to:
Exchange the token for a **CustomerIdentifier**, **CustomerAWSAccountId**, and **ProductCode** by calling the **ResolveCustomer API operation** in the AWS Marketplace Metering Service.
How should I do this using the AWS SDK for Java V2?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.